# Cannot read property 'mode' of undefined error in flatpickr.js

Tags: javascript, onchange, dom-events, flatpickr

I am using 2 flatpickr calendar instances to show `start` and `end` time interval. When user alters `start` time, I additionally update the `minDate` value for the `end` time and similarly on any update in the `end` time I update the `maxDate` value of the `start` time. My code looks like below:

```
onPageLand() {
    var startTimeConfig = {
        datetime: {
            enableTime: true,
            maxDate: new Date(<<--initial end time-->>),
            dateFormat: "Y-m-d H:i",
            defaultDate: new Date(<<--initial start time-->>),
            onClose: function (selectedDates, dateStr, instance) {
                let changedStartTime = new Date(dateStr);
                if (startTime.toString() != changedStartTime.toString()) {
                    startTime = changedStartTime;
                    //take update actions
                }

                endTimeConfig.datetime.minDate = changedStartTime;
                renderCalendar(startTimeConfig, endTimeConfig, calendarInstances);
            },
            onChange: function () {
            }
        }
    }


    var endTimeConfig = {
        datetime: {
            enableTime: true,
            minDate: new Date(<<--initial start time-->>),
            dateFormat: "Y-m-d H:i",
            defaultDate: new Date(<<--initial end time-->>),
            onClose: function (selectedDates, dateStr, instance) {
                let changedEndTime = new Date(dateStr);
                if (endTime.toString() != changedEndTime.toString()) {
                    endTime = changedEndTime;
                    //take update actions
                }

                startTimeConfig.datetime.maxDate = changedEndTime;
                renderCalendar(startTimeConfig, endTimeConfig, calendarInstances);
            },
            onChange: function() {
            }
        }
    }
    renderCalendar(startTimeConfig, endTimeConfig, calendarInstances);
}


function renderCalendar(startTimeConfig, endTimeConfig, calendarInstances) {
    var configs = [startTimeConfig, endTimeConfig];
    if (configs.length === calendarInstances.length) {
        for (var i = 0; i < calendarInstances.length; i++) {
            console.log(configs[i][calendarInstances[i].getAttribute("data-id")]);
            flatpickr(calendarInstances[i], configs[i][calendarInstances[i].getAttribute("data-id")] || {});
        }
    }
}
```

On the above code when I change a value in `start` or `end` date and close the calendar pop up, I get the below error on console:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'mode' of undefined
>   at S (calendar.js:630)
>   at HTMLDocument. (calendar.js:489)
>   S @ calendar.js:630
>   (anonymous) @ calendar.js:489

How to solve the above issue?

PS: My intention is to

1. Fire update function in `onClose`
2. Keep the `minDate` of `end` time selection equal to the `start` time selection and `maxDate` of the `start` time selection equal to the `end` time selection always.

Answer (score -1):

This occurred for me when attempting to destroy the flatpickr instance in the close() callback, and it didn't really seem to cause any harm in my case. However, it's usually not necessary to destroy the flatpickr instance, especially if you use same selector since it will automatically destroy any previous instance on that selector (at least according to the documentation).